# How to represent mapped type in type-graphql?

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

How can i represent a mapped type in a type-graphql object type?

```
type Data<T> = { [key: string]: keyof T };
```

Into:

```
@ObjectType()
class DataQL<T> implements Data<T> {
    @Field()
    [key: string]: keyof T
}
```

Comment: Are you trying the dynamically implement an interface?